# Can we have a shorthand URL for user profile pages?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, users

Can we have a shorthand URL for user profile pages?

E.g. my profile is under `https://stackoverflow.com/users/3227403/pid` but if I want to write it on a blackboard while lecturing it's unwieldy.

It would be nice to have a shortcut URL like `so-user.com/pid` redirecting to the actual profile page on SO.

Homonymy could be solved by letting users opt-in to this functionality and activating it only for the first user opting-in. That's harsh but it works and is very simple to implement.

That's just an idea that came up in mind and maybe it's not even that much useful for most users. Just throwing this out here.

Comment: Why not use a link shortener like bit.ly or goo.gl?

Comment: I'm curious why you'd ever need to write it on a blackboard? Aside from the fact that you could also send a email (or other message) to the participants, why would a group of people need to access your profile?

Comment: You could just write your user id and let people search for it ;) Make those rascals work for it.

Comment: What's wrong with saying something like `so.com/u/3227403`? `so` is clearly stack overflow and all you need to get to a user is `/u/<id>`

Comment: Problem with `so-user.com/pid` is that multiple users are permitted to have the same display name. What if someone else has the display name `pid`? A user ID must exist in the URL to avoid collisions, and for that, `/u/3227403/` works just fine, and is extremely short already

Comment: Also, homonymy is not the only problem when you yourself can change display name every 30 days. Should the shortener identifier change too?

Comment: Maybe this should have been a discussion. I vote to close because I don't want to delete it, maybe someone will take this advice to heart. Paulie_D: this is a good idea, maybe I'll do this. Cerbrus: too broad to explain, not all CS classes are about computers, sometimes it's about culture and community. Gimby: yeah! Scourge those lazy ***** :) Nick A the Popcorn King: good idea, too! CertainPerformance: that's homonymy. Andrew T.: thanks! Didn't know about that, this makes my idea VERY BAD! -- thanks everybody for sharing and clearing up my mind!

Comment: Is `stackoverflow.com/users/3227403` too long?

Comment: Just set up your link as a QR code and stick that on the blackboard. I'm sure your students have iPhones.

Comment: @AdrianMole You have little faith in the young generation! Surely they have Androids :-D

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I got these redirects up and running. The domain supports https as well as http.

```
so-user.com/ => stackoverflow.com/users/
meta.so-user.com/ => meta.stackoverflow.com/users/
cv.so-user.com/ => stackoverflow.com/cv/
story.so-user.com/ => stackoverflow.com/story/
```

E.g.: [so-user.com/584192](https://so-user.com/584192), [cv.so-user.com/samliew](https://cv.so-user.com/samliew)

As the DNS records simply forwards the path name, you can also link to special URLs and query parameters:

https://so-user.com/?tab=moderators
https://so-user.com/584192?tab=profile
https://so-user.com/current
https://so-user.com/current?tab=badges
https://so-user.com/current?tab=favorites
https://so-user.com/current?tab=favorites&sort=votes
https://so-user.com/email/settings/current (even settings pages)